# How to target specific search form with pre_get_posts?

Tags: php, search, wordpress

On my blog page i have 2 default wordpress search forms, 1 in the header that should search for everything and 1 in the sidebar that should only search for posts.

i managed to change to query to suit my needs with pre_get_posts, but it changes it for both search forms

```
function exclude_pages($query) {
  if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'post');
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_pages');
```

How can i specify that the function only changes the query for the search form in the sidebar?

Answer (score 2):

Add a hidden field to one of your search forms then check if a value has been set for it in `pre_get_posts`.

Inside the sidebar form add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="posts-only" value="1" />
```

Then change this:

```
if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'post');
}
```

To:

```
// Check if posts only value has been set and equal to 1. Return if not.
if ( ! isset( $_GET['posts-only'] ) || 1 !== $_GET['posts-only'] ) {
    return false;
}

if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'post') ;
}
```